# Java swing - list.add issues

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm creating a GUI for use in a judged sporting event. There are 6 judges and they each input their score into the GUI. They then hit calculate, and the program is meant to sort the numbers from low to high and then take the numbers from position 1 through 4 and give an average.

I have written the code for input via console and that works, but when I try my Gui the 'list.add' doesn't work. I don't know if I am meant to use something else.

```
    btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            inGui = new Scanner (System.in);
            double firstRun = getAverageOfRun(1);
            double secondRun = getAverageOfRun(2);
            double best;

            if (firstRun > secondRun) {
                best = firstRun;
            } else {
                best = secondRun;
            }
            textFieldRun1Score.setText(Double.toString(best));
            }
        private double getAverageOfRun (int runNumber) {
            double total, avg;
            int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6;
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(textFieldRun1Score1.getText());

            System.out.print(""+runNumber +": ");
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score1.getText());
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score2.getText());
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score3.getText());
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score4.getText());
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score5.getText());
            list.add(textFieldRun1Score6.getText());

            Collections.sort(list);

            total = list.get(1) + list.get(2) + list.get(3) + list.get(4);

            avg = total / 4;

            textFieldBestScore.setText(Double.toString(avg));
            return avg;

        }
```

Comment: "doesn't want to work", what it says! Show the error details.

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember that for next time.All sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't compile for a simple reason: type mismatch.
Just split this line:

```
list.add(textFieldRun1Score1.getText());
```

up: `list.add(...)` expects an `int` as parameter (since it's templatetype is `Integer`), `textFieldRun1Score1.getText()` returns a `String`. Thus you'll have to convert from `String` to `int` first. Most common way to solve this is `int value = Integer.parseInt(string);`

Answer (score 1):

```
list.add(textFieldRun1Score1.getText());
```

won't work because you try to add a `String` to a list of `Integers`

Parse the `String` to an `Integer` first:

```
list.add(Integer.parseInt(textFieldRun1Score1.getText()));
```

.

**edit** (not an answer to your question, but a general advice):

Instead of doing:

```
double best;

if (firstRun > secondRun) {
    best = firstRun;
} else {
    best = secondRun;
}
```

simply use: `double best = Math.max(firstRun, secondRun);`

Comment: Thanks! I changed the 'double' and it works. Makes it a bit neater